# Number pad side buttons on Mac

Tags: mac, mouse, button-remapping, mouse-buttons

I am considering purchasing a “gaming” mouse for my Mac with 12 side buttons and I would like to map those side buttons (buttons 1-9) to press the corresponding numbers on a keyboard. I’ve found 3 or 4 different programs that say they can do this for gestures on a trackpad. Is there anything available that can do this?

Comment: Software should be provided by the mouse manufacturer to do exactly this. It is possible that they only have Windows drivers, in which case I (personally) would look for a mouse from a different manufacturer. If you add the manufacturer make/model information to your question we will likely be able to help you better with this.

Answer (score 0):

UtechSmart Venus Gaming Mouse RGB... [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00FNKMVUO?ref=ppx_pop_mob_ap_share](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FNKMVUO)

There’s the Amazon link. It’s kinda difficult to find mice with 12 side buttons because there’s not many of them, let alone ones for Mac.